# How to get point coordinates from distance matrix?

Tags: numpy, matrix, machine-learning, pca

I have the following data set, each data is an array with 128 elements.

```
[-0.08  0.23  0.21 -0.17  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.11 -0.04  0.03 -0.04 -0.1
 -0.04 -0.03  0.11 -0.04 -0.07 -0.02 -0.04 -0.16  0.07  0.16 -0.07 -0.13
  0.06 -0.04  0.03  0.12  0.15  0.04 -0.05 -0.19  0.06  0.02  0.1  -0.1
  0.09 -0.03  0.03  0.01  0.03 -0.04  0.12  0.07  0.    0.19  0.04 -0.07
 -0.17 -0.09  0.02  0.15 -0.1   0.03 -0.01  0.03  0.01 -0.11 -0.09 -0.05
  0.05 -0.11 -0.1   0.13  0.03 -0.07 -0.04  0.04  0.04  0.09  0.09 -0.04
 -0.02 -0.16  0.08  0.11 -0.12  0.09  0.05 -0.03 -0.02  0.06  0.13  0.23
  0.05 -0.04  0.04  0.05  0.01  0.14 -0.05 -0.07 -0.1   0.01 -0.11 -0.1
  0.02  0.05 -0.02 -0.02 -0.01  0.12  0.03 -0.01 -0.06 -0.05 -0.03  0.11
  0.05 -0.1   0.09 -0.12 -0.2   0.06  0.03  0.   -0.08 -0.06 -0.04  0.
  0.07  0.06 -0.05  0.01  0.13 -0.03  0.14  0.01]

[ 0.13  0.02  0.03  0.08 -0.01  0.    0.03 -0.06 -0.09 -0.11  0.02  0.12
 -0.01 -0.14 -0.1   0.08 -0.02 -0.08 -0.13  0.1   0.01  0.15  0.    0.09
 -0.05  0.13  0.04 -0.05  0.04  0.07 -0.12  0.14 -0.08  0.09 -0.09 -0.13
 -0.08  0.15 -0.03  0.1  -0.04  0.   -0.05  0.07  0.01  0.04  0.08 -0.08
 -0.08  0.1   0.22  0.07 -0.05  0.    0.06 -0.11 -0.01  0.08  0.06  0.   -0.
 -0.09  0.04  0.06 -0.04 -0.17  0.04 -0.06 -0.05  0.01 -0.04 -0.01  0.06
  0.17 -0.02 -0.08 -0.02 -0.06 -0.05  0.21  0.17 -0.02  0.02 -0.12  0.04
 -0.16  0.04 -0.08 -0.08  0.01 -0.05 -0.01 -0.15  0.08 -0.03  0.09  0.13
 -0.08  0.07 -0.07 -0.06  0.1  -0.02  0.21 -0.15 -0.13 -0.06  0.14  0.07
 -0.08  0.15  0.18 -0.11  0.05 -0.   -0.   -0.08 -0.04 -0.03  0.03 -0.03
  0.14  0.05 -0.04  0.1  -0.03  0.07 -0.12]

[-0.01  0.22  0.2  -0.17 -0.04  0.04  0.01  0.14 -0.07  0.01 -0.04 -0.16
  0.    0.11  0.15 -0.09  0.03 -0.07 -0.04 -0.19  0.06  0.15 -0.07 -0.06
  0.07 -0.1   0.    0.17  0.13  0.02 -0.   -0.17 -0.01  0.02  0.02 -0.06
  0.04  0.01  0.03  0.09 -0.03  0.02  0.01 -0.03  0.07  0.19 -0.05 -0.06
 -0.13 -0.1   0.03  0.23 -0.04  0.02 -0.07  0.01  0.03 -0.02 -0.02 -0.08
  0.04 -0.01 -0.15  0.08 -0.1  -0.01  0.05  0.12  0.03  0.07  0.13 -0.03
 -0.05 -0.14  0.11  0.11 -0.11 -0.    0.07  0.04 -0.02  0.04  0.15  0.14
  0.07 -0.03  0.04 -0.04 -0.02  0.08 -0.07 -0.08 -0.    0.04 -0.09 -0.1
  0.05 -0.01 -0.03 -0.02  0.    0.16  0.02  0.07 -0.15 -0.02 -0.09  0.05
  0.06 -0.15  0.14 -0.1  -0.21  0.07  0.03  0.06 -0.11 -0.05 -0.02  0.
  0.03  0.02 -0.07  0.01  0.12 -0.03  0.09  0.01]

[ 0.18 -0.04 -0.02  0.06 -0.05  0.07  0.02  0.16  0.   -0.02  0.1   0.06
  0.04 -0.12 -0.06  0.04  0.06 -0.05 -0.17  0.09  0.03  0.08  0.03  0.03
 -0.13 -0.02  0.05 -0.07 -0.09 -0.01 -0.11  0.05  0.04  0.13 -0.13 -0.06
 -0.07  0.1  -0.16  0.06 -0.1  -0.04 -0.16  0.02  0.02  0.02 -0.08 -0.06
 -0.1   0.15  0.2   0.08 -0.1   0.01 -0.01 -0.06 -0.03 -0.1   0.06  0.04
 -0.03 -0.12 -0.04 -0.04 -0.02 -0.21 -0.01  0.09 -0.05  0.05  0.02 -0.1
 -0.01 -0.05 -0.09  0.02  0.04 -0.01 -0.07  0.15 -0.01 -0.16 -0.02 -0.09
  0.01 -0.    0.05 -0.11 -0.    0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.18  0.13 -0.04  0.11
  0.09 -0.18 -0.03 -0.01  0.07  0.12 -0.06  0.05 -0.03 -0.12 -0.05  0.01
 -0.01 -0.1   0.    0.1  -0.02 -0.03  0.09  0.   -0.06 -0.05  0.03  0.08
 -0.04  0.03  0.07  0.09  0.29 -0.07  0.19 -0.07]
```

From the dataset, I get the distance matrix between every two nodes. The distance is euclidean distance.

```
[[-inf       , -1.37174386, -0.90543197, -1.40566222],
 [-1.37174386,        -inf, -1.33795484, -0.5526271 ],
 [-0.90543197, -1.33795484,        -inf, -1.37944292],
 [-1.40566222, -0.5526271 , -1.37944292,        -inf]]
```

Now from the distance matrix, I want make a 3D UI where a node can represent where the data is. How can I get the x, y, z coordinates of each data node. 
Or how can I convert the 128 elements array to the value of x, y, z where the distances remain the same?

Answer (score 1):

Your data exist in 128 dimensions, so you're asking for a Euclidean distance-preserving projection into 3 dimensions. Nothing works perfectly. The t-SNE algorithm tends to give aesthetically pleasing results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PCA to convert your high dimensional matrix to a 3D or 2D matrix.
Assign to X either your distance matrix or your initial matrix (doesn't matter which one check the output visualisation and choose the one that looks more reasonable).
Here is a [Python Scikit-learn implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = your distance matrix or your initial matrix
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
X3d = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

For 2D drawing set n_components to 2.

Comment: I got ValueError: n_components=3 invalid for n_features=1 while fit_transform my data matrix. My data matrix is 128 * 1.

Comment: A data matrix 128x1 means you have 128 samples each 1 dimensional (1 feature) so you won't be able to reduce the dimensionality from 1 to 3! Your input matrix should have several samples and more than 3 features (n_sampleXn_features) and the number of features should be more than the n_components. As input you should give all your data in the matrix not only one sample. so if one sample is 128 x 1 you first transpose it to get 1 x 128 then you stack all your samples to get n_samples x 128 then use it as input with n_components=3 and that's done.